# Pin a personal view in D365

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-365

How to I pin a personal view in D365. It is a child entity to the case entity (not in the left navigation menu).
It is not appearing on the recent items in the main page when I go Advanced find -> Saved views and run the view.
Recent items are appearing for the views and record from the main page which I could pin from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work, add/replace this part in browser address bar - `&pagetype=entitylist&etn=YOUR_ENTITY_NAME`.

Make sure you’re changing the entity name, then this will land on that main grid page. From there you can change to personal view and pin it.

If you know the view guid - then try similar to this:

```
Url="/main.aspx?appid=e2bc1066-488f-eb11-b1ac-000d3a56ead9&pagetype=entitylist&etn=account&viewid=%7b<GUID value of view id>%7d"
```

[Read more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/model-driven-apps/open-forms-views-dialogs-reports-url?WT.mc_id=DX-MVP-5004422#display-a-view-in-the-application-navigation-using-the-site-map)